# The session is unavailable because no secret key was set. Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret

Tags: python, authentication, flask, session, jwt

This is my code, i think it is right but all i received is :
RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret
Please help me, i can not find how to solve

```
# flask imports
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response,render_template,session, Blueprint
import jwt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from functools import wraps
from db.models.account import Accounts
from db.models.teachers import Teacher
import db
from db.models import db

login_bp = Blueprint('login', __name__)
# creates Flask object
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'g}/lVKCOmv)kvhWBNV;+}_}.eJ(]n`Y:d,O|q44lgMIHeHp|G;27>KS2,ynEDhJ'
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
login_bp.config = {}
login_bp.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'g}/lVKCOmv)kvhWBNV;+}_}.eJ(]n`Y:d,O|q44lgMIHeHp|G;27>KS2,ynEDhJ'
def token_required(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        token = request.args.get('token')
        if not token:
            return jsonify({'Alert': 'Token is missing'})
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, login.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({'Alert': e})
    return decorator

@login_bp.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def handle_login():
    if Accounts.check_exists_account(request): #Đoạn này để handle nếu email và password có trong cơ sở dữ liệu
        session['logged_in'] = True
        token = jwt.encode({
            'user': request.form['email'],
            'expiration': str(datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=120))
        }, login_bp.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        return jsonify({'token': token.decode('utf-8')})
    else:
        return make_response('Unable to verify' ,403,{'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm: Authentication Failed'})
@login_bp.route('/auth')
@token_required
def auth():
    return 'JWT is verified. Welcome to your dashboard !  '
```

I try to see something on SOF but nothing can help me

Comment: Please set the title as a question (not the error log), provide the stacktrace, and what you did to run into the problem. Also don't post any secrets :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.